# 'ApplicationSignInManager' not found (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, owin

I'm following the tutorial in this link:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

However, while I am doing what is being instructed on the article, the ApplicationSignInManager class specified in the tutorial is not existing in the project I'm building. I tried to look in search engines for possible answers but failed to find any. I just like to know where can I find the dll that contains this class so I could include it to my project and proceed with the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @trailmax I just found the original source of this. The project files are also attached to the tutorial from the start. Its just under IdentityConfig.cs file. here's how it's implemented:

IdentityConfig.cs

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually `ApplicationSignInManager` is part of your project, only inherits from `SignInManager<TUser, TKey>`. Something like this should do:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(UserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<UserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Perhaps you should've asked this question on the original resource.